# I think I found a bug in WebKit (or jQuery), can others confirm?

Tags: jquery, safari, webkit, google-chrome

I believe I have found a bug in WebKit. It involves outerWidth(true) (and I assume outerHeight(true) ) in jQuery.

In every browser but Safari and Chrome, the third box is 200. In Safari and Chrome, it is (almost) the width of my screen.

Click [here](http://x3non.com/image/alec/147/outerWidth%20true%20fail.png) to see my results:
[image: inline image not found.]
<sub>(source: [x3non.com](http://x3non.com/image/alec/147/outerWidth%20true%20fail.png))</sub>

You can test is for yourself here: http://ramblingwood.com/sandbox/webkit-bug/test.html

I used this test file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    input {
      width: 50%;
      height: 1em;
      font-size: 1em;
    }
 #testBox {margin-left:100px;width:100px;}
 #testBox2 {padding-left:100px;width:100px;}
 #testBox3 {border-left:100px black solid;width:100px;}
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function init(){
      $('#w1').val($('#testBox').width());
      $('#ow1').val($('#testBox').outerWidth());
      $('#owt1').val($('#testBox').outerWidth(true));
      $('#w2').val($('#testBox2').width());
      $('#ow2').val($('#testBox2').outerWidth());
      $('#owt2').val($('#testBox2').outerWidth(true));
      $('#w3').val($('#testBox3').width());
      $('#ow3').val($('#testBox3').outerWidth());
      $('#owt3').val($('#testBox3').outerWidth(true));
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
      init();

      $(window).resize(function(){
        init();
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
 <div id="testBox">test</div>
  <p>width() <input type="text" id="w1" /></p>
  <p>outerWidth() <input type="text" id="ow1" /></p>
  <p>outerWidth(true) <input type="text" id="owt1" /></p>

 <div id="testBox2">test2</div>
  <p>width() <input type="text" id="w2" /></p>
  <p>outerWidth() <input type="text" id="ow2" /></p>
  <p>outerWidth(true) <input type="text" id="owt2" /></p>

 <div id="testBox3">test3</div>
  <p>width() <input type="text" id="w3" /></p>
  <p>outerWidth() <input type="text" id="ow3" /></p>
  <p>outerWidth(true) <input type="text" id="owt3" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chrome's DOM inspector confirms that this is a WebKit issue; the div gets a large right margin, even if you try to override `margin-right`. Some things that force the margin to be calculated correctly include `float: left` and `display: inline-block`. Also if you put the div inside of another sized div, its `outerWidth(true)` will give the `innerWidth` of the containing div, which could be a useful real-world workaround -- just wrap it in a div with `margin: 0; padding: 0; width: XXX`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug in finding the outer width. Webkit actually renders the divs as having large right margins. Since the right margin extends (almost) to the right edge, you get the larger outer width.

I'm not sure if this is the "correct" way to render it, but if there's a specification that says that the right margin shouldn't extend out, then this would be a bug in WebKit.

Comment: in either case, it is really fricken annoying when writing cross browser code.

Answer (score 1):

My experiences confirm this as well - it's a Webkit bug and needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

if you set size to say 1 on your input field it fixes the bug - testet in Chrome and Safari

Answer (score 0):

I can also confirm this.

It is really odd that Webkit does this, and I can't imagine why anyone would think that this is a good idea.

I wonder if Chrome 4 fixes this.